# How can I keep track of users in wordpress those are not logged in?

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I want to integrate a WordPress site with Mix panel. So I need to set cookie for each user visiting our site. Then I have to count their no of visit and save it MySQL. For now I am using

[image]

Comment: So, the problem is?

Comment: Is this the right way ? I want to store these in database. But Whenever I write
$sql= "INSERT INTO fullon_visit_count(unreg_user_id,user_visit_count) VALUES ($userId,$user_visit)";
mysqli_query($sql); there is no change in the database.

Answer (score 0):

The problem in this script is the logic itself - you are generating UID every time, so there is no way to match any existing UID cookie, on each visit you will write brand new cookie with this generated UID. Moreover is a wrong approach to use UID as cookie name (again you can't match it with already written cookie), so check this out:

```
<?php
    if (!isset($_COOKIE['swain_uid'])) {
        $guid = com_create_guid();
        $ucnt = 1;
    } else {
        $guid = $_COOKIE['swain_uid'];
        $ucnt = ++$_COOKIE['swain_cnt'];
    }
    setcookie('swain_uid', $guid);
    setcookie('swain_cnt', $ucnt);
    print_r($_COOKIE); //for debug purposes only, remove it on production.
?>
```

This will create two cookies with static names - one for UID and one for the count. Then you will be able to count each user's visit (unless the user has clear his cookies).

**UPDATE:**

Regarding database records, simply create table where UID to be primary key and do `INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` after cookie logic:

MySQL table:

```
CREATE TABLE `visit_count` (
  `userId` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `userVisit` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`userId`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

PHP (in addition with script above):

```
    $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'test') or die(mysqli_error($con));
    $query = "INSERT INTO visit_count 
          (userId, userVisit) 
      VALUES 
          ('".$guid."', ".$ucnt.") 
      ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE userVisit = ".$ucnt;
    mysqli_query($con, $query) or die(mysqli_error($con));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I want to store it in the database so can i put the sql query just after it ? 
$sql= "INSERT INTO visit_count(swain_uid,swain_cnt) VALUES ($userId,$user_visit)";
mysqli_query($sql); 

or should I do anything else ?

Comment: I am thinking to include this code in header.php of my wordpress website in local host . Will it be right ?

Comment: No, better add it in on top in function.php in your root theme folder.

Comment: for live database what changes should i do in database connection part ?

Comment: Use built-in WP functions for DB query.